# converting sequence of nucleotide into 2D array of integers

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am trying to convert nucleotide to integer using the following mapping:

```
A -> 0
C -> 1
G -> 2
T -> 3
```

The sequence of nucleotide is saved in a pandas dataframe and it looks like:

```
           0
0   GGATAATA
1   CGATAACC
```

I have used the df.apply() method to do the task. Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
a = ["GGATAATA","CGATAACC"]
d = dict(zip('A C G T'.split(), range(4)))
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
mapping = df[0].apply(lambda s: np.array([d[i] for i in s]))
```

It returns the following numpy array which is one dimensional:

```
print(mapping.values)
array([array([2, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 3, 0]), array([1, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1, 1])],
      dtype=object)
```

However, the expected output should be two dimensional array:

```
[[2,2,0,3,0,0,3,0],
[1,2,0,3,0,0,1,1]]
```

Comment: do you have the same length of nucleotide in the column?

Comment: yes it is same throughout the column

Comment: you can try `np.concatenate(mapping.tolist()).ravel().reshape(-1, 8)` **8** is #'s of nucleotides in the column

Answer (score 1):

Use `map`:

```
list(map(lambda x: list(map(lambda c: d[c], list(x))), df[0]))
```

**Output**

```
[[2, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 3, 0], [1, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1, 1]]
```

or

```
df[0].agg(list).explode().replace(d).groupby(level=0).agg(list).tolist()
```

I think the first solusion is faster

```
%%timeit
list(map(lambda x: list(map(lambda c: d[c], list(x))), df[0]))
11.7 µs ± 392 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

---

```
%%timeit
df[0].agg(list).explode().replace(d).groupby(level=0).agg(list).tolist()
5.02 ms ± 697 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC

```
df['0'].apply(list).explode().replace(d).groupby(level=0).agg(list).to_list()
Out[579]: [[2, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 3, 0], [1, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1, 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

using `.str.split()` and `stack` with `map`

```
seq = {'A' : 0,
'C' : 1,
'G' : 2,
'T' : 3}

df[0].str.split('',expand=True).stack().map(seq).dropna().groupby(level=0).agg(list)

#out:

0    [2.0, 2.0, 0.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 0.0]
1    [1.0, 2.0, 0.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0]
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

a = ["GGATAATA","CGATAACC"]
d = dict(zip('A C G T'.split(), range(4)))
df = pd.DataFrame(a)

# implement mapping
mapping = str.maketrans('ACGT', '0123')
df[0] = df[0].map(lambda x: x.translate(mapping))

# expected output
output = df[0].map(lambda x: [int(x) for i in  list(x)]).tolist()
```